# Typescript not compiling

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to compile my trypescript app on windows, with

```
C:/nodejs/tsc.cmd --sourcemap app.ts --module
```

and this is the error that I get:

```
C:\nodejs\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:55708
                    type = type.toLowerCase();
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at Object.opts.option.set (C:\nodejs\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:55708:33)
    at OptionsParser.parse (C:\nodejs\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:55258:36)
    at BatchCompiler.parseOptions (C:\nodejs\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:55771:18)
    at BatchCompiler.batchCompile (C:\nodejs\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:55328:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nodejs\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js:56015:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Ideally, it says that there is a problem with the typescript library itself, but that seems highly unlikely.

I install typescript through `npm instal typescript` and my version is `0.9.1`, any help would be highly appreciated.

This is my typescript code, that I am trying to compile:

```
///<reference path='node/node.d.ts' />
///<reference path='node/express.d.ts' />

import http = module("http")
import path = module("path")
import express = module("express")
import index = module("./routes/index")
import user = module("./routes/user")

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', index.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the module type. Since its node js it would be "commonjs" :

```
C:/nodejs/tsc.cmd --sourcemap app.ts --module "commonjs"
```

**Update:** To fix http not found compile time error here is a quick typescript definition:

```
declare module "http"{
}
```

Comment: Now it gives me errors, saying that file "http" was not found.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Thats a different question but updated answer :)